# Ruby on rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Pessoal estou começando em Ruby on Rails e tive um problema com as chamadas *nested routes*:

```
 class Maquina < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :verificacaos
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :verificacaos
    end

    class Verificacao < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :maquina
    end

      resources :maquinas do
        resources :verificacaos
      end
```

Foram essas as linhas que eu alterei no código que me gerou a **`url:maquinas/:maquinas_id/verificacaos`**

Porém ele não mostra somente a verificação especifica para a maquina do `ip` requisitado, e sim todas as maquinas independente do computador ao qual ela está relacionada.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Edit: Contoler Maquina

```
class MaquinasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_maquina, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /maquinas
  def index
    @maquinas = Maquina.all

    render json: @maquinas
  end

  # GET /maquinas/1
  def show
    render json: @maquina
  end

  # POST /maquinas
  def create
    @maquina = Maquina.new(maquina_params)

    if @maquina.save
      render json: @maquina, status: :created, location: @maquina
    else
      render json: @maquina.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /maquinas/1
  def update
    if @maquina.update(maquina_params)
      render json: @maquina
    else
      render json: @maquina.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /maquinas/1
  def destroy
    @maquina.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share coMon setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_maquina
      @maquina = Maquina.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def maquina_params
      params.require(:maquina).permit(:marca, :modelo, :numeroPatrimonio, :numeroSerie, :nomeMaquina, :usuarioMaquina, :processador, :memoriaRam, :hd, :sistemaOperacional, :setor, :descricao)
    end
end
```

Controler Verificação

```
class VerificacaosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_verificacao, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /verificacaos
  def index
    @verificacaos = Verificacao.all

    render json: @verificacaos
  end

  # GET /verificacaos/1
  def show
    render json: @verificacao
  end

  # POST /verificacaos
  def create
    @verificacao = Verificacao.new(verificacao_params)

    if @verificacao.save
      render json: @verificacao, status: :created, location: @verificacao
    else
      render json: @verificacao.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /verificacaos/1
  def update
    if @verificacao.update(verificacao_params)
      render json: @verificacao
    else
      render json: @verificacao.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /verificacaos/1
  def destroy
    @verificacao.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_verificacao
      @verificacao = Verificacao.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def verificacao_params
      params.require(:verificacao).permit(:data, :status, :verificadoPor, :maquina_id, :observacao)
    end
end
```

Comment: Você pode postar o código dos controllers também?

Comment: Eu não alterei os controlers, pelas minhas pesquisas são eles que eu preciso alterar, mas não sei como

Comment: Se qualquer forma estão ai

Comment: Você quer ver uma verificação específica de uma máquina específica, correto?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo, por exemplo, quando eu digitar maquinas/:maquinas_id/verificacaos tem que aparecer somente as verificações que tiverem a maquina_id igual a que foi colocada na url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está no `VerificacaosController`. A url `maquinas/:maquinas_id/verificacaos` é processada pela action `index`, a qual está retornando tudo:

```
# GET /verificacaos
def index
    @verificacaos = Verificacao.all

    render json: @verificacaos
end
```

Você só precisa incluir `:maquinas_id` na query:

```
# GET /verificacaos
def index
    @verificacaos = Verificacao.where(maquina_id: params[:maquina_id])

    render json: @verificacaos
end
```

E a action vai trazer somente os objetos relevantes.

Comment: Cara, eu te amo, muito kkkk